# How to improve AWS Glue's performance?

Tags: performance, amazon-web-services, etl, aws-glue

I have a simple job on AWS that takes more than 25 minutes. I changed the number of DPUs from 10 to 100 (the max allowed), the job still takes 13 minutes.

Any other suggestions on improving the performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless CPU or memory was a bottleneck for your existing job, adding more DPUs (i.e. more CPU and memory) wouldn't benefit your job significantly. At least the benefits will not be linear, i.e. 10 times more DPU doesn't mean that the job will run 10 times faster.

I suggest that you gradually increase the number of DPUs to look at performance gains, and you will notice that after a certain point adding more DPUs doesn't have a major impact on performance and that probably is the right amount of DPUs for your job.

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed the same behavior.

My understanding is that the job time includes spinning up an EMR cluster, which takes several minutes. So if it takes.. say 8 minutes (just a guess), then your job time went from 17 -> 5.

Answer (score 1):

Can we take a look at your job? Sometimes simple may not be performant. We've found that simple things like using the DynamicFrame.map transformation is really slow and you might be better off using a tmp table and mapping your data using the SQLContext